# How to skip Authentication for a resource in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

We have a working react-admin app with authentication up and running.

But now we have to add a resource that should be accessible without logging in. How can we do this?

Our `App.js` (shortened) looks like this:

```js
<Admin authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={simpleRestProvider(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/v1`, httpClient)}>
    <Resource name={'posts'} list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} create={PostCreate} icon={PostIcon} show={PostShow}/>
    <Resource name={'messages'} create={MessagesCreate}/>
</Admin>
```

We want `messages` to be accessible without authentication. But all the other resources (removed from the snippet above) should still be protected by the `authProvider`.

We didn't find anything in the official docs about that. Only [Checking Credentials During Navigation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#checking-credentials-during-navigation). But according to [this issue](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2617) and [this comment](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2617#issuecomment-532261178) it is no longer possible to do this.

Can anyone help us with this?

Thanks in advance.